# Force Incremental Déjà-dup-Backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I understand that Déjà-Dup ocassionally does  full backups, so that a single corrupted backup in the chain will not invalidate all following backups. But since I am going to reinstall the system, I would like to have one final backup. Déjà-Dup says, that it is time for a full backup, which would be a waste of space in this case.

Question: Can I force Déjà-Dup to create only an incremental backup?

*Edit:* I have forgotten to mention, that déjà-dup is set up to backup two different folders

Comment: if you are going to reinstall, I would recommend a full backup

Comment: Yeah, I think I will do a full backup. It is not worth the struggel and I will not need the old ones, if I think about it

Answer (score 3):

You can force an incremental backup by using the command line tool `duplicity`.

`man duplicity` states that it supports the command

```
 incr <folder> <url>
               If this is requested an incremental backup will be performed.
               Duplicity will abort if no old signatures can be found.
```

If you have `deja-dup` set up to back up from many different folders this might be a clumsy or unworkable action (I am not a sophisticated `duplicity` user). However if you are just backing up `home` or something simple it could work for you.

Consult `man duplicity` for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I do indeed backup two different folders, I forgot to mention it in the original question